# C++ Counting words in a file between two words

Tags: c++, file, count, words

I am currently trying to count the number of words in a file. After this, I plan to make it count the words between two words in the file. For example. My file may contain. "Hello my name is James". I want to count the words, so 5. And then I would like to count the number of words between "Hello" and "James", so the answer would be 3. I am having trouble with accomplishing both tasks. 
Mainly due to not being exactly sure how to structure my code.
Any help on here would be greatly appreciated. The code I am currently using is using spaces to count the words.

Here is my code:

readwords.cpp

```
string ReadWords::getNextWord()
{
    bool pWord = false;
    char c;
    while((c = wordfile.get()) !=EOF)
    {
        if (!(isspace(c)))
        {
            nextword.append(1, c);
        }

        return nextword;
    }
}

bool ReadWords::isNextWord()
{
    if(!wordfile.eof())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
main()
{
    int count = 0;
    ReadWords rw("hamlet.txt");
    while(rw.isNextWord()){
        rw.getNextWord();
                count++;
    }
    cout << count;
    rw.close();
}
```

What it does at the moment is counts the number of characters. I'm sure its just a simple fix and something silly that I'm missing. But I've been trying for long enough to go searching for some help.

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: c++? append tokenized words to vector, find the two words, subtract the indices. treat repeated words however you want

Comment: also you realize isNextWord() is pretty much pointless, right? just prepend a ! in your original condition or take the alternate path

Comment: I would personally recommend reading the words into a char array to start. The file will be easier to work with once it's in memory, and it will allow you to deal with the general case - ie GetWordCountBetween(string word1, string word2) without doing more file IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than parse the file character-by-character, you can simply use `istream::operator<<()` to read whitespace-separated words. `<<` returns the stream, which evaluates to `true` as a `bool` when the stream can still be read from.

```
vector<string> words;
string word;
while (wordfile >> word)
    words.push_back(word);
```

There is a common formulation of this using the `<iterator>` and `<algorithm>` utilities, which is more verbose, but can be composed with other iterator algorithms:

```
istream_iterator<string> input(wordfile), end;
copy(input, end, back_inserter(words));
```

Then you have the number of words and can do with them whatever you like:

```
words.size()
```

If you want to find `"Hello"` and `"James"`, use `find()` from the `<algorithm>` header to get iterators to their positions:

```
// Find "Hello" anywhere in 'words'.
const auto hello = find(words.begin(), words.end(), "Hello");

// Find "James" anywhere after 'hello' in 'words'.
const auto james = find(hello, words.end(), "James");
```

If they’re not in the vector, `find()` will return `words.end()`; ignoring error checking for the purpose of illustration, you can count the number of words between them by taking their difference, adjusting for the inclusion of `"Hello"` in the range:

```
const auto count = james - (hello + 1);
```

You can use `operator-()` here because `std::vector::iterator` is a “random-access iterator”. More generally, you could use `std::distance()` from `<iterator>`:

```
const auto count = distance(hello, james) - 1;
```

Which has the advantage of being more descriptive of what you’re actually doing. Also, for future reference, this kind of code:

```
bool f() {
    if (x) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can be simplified to just:

```
bool f() {
    return x;
}
```

Since `x` is already being converted to `bool` for the `if`.

Comment: `find(words.begin(), words.end(), "James")` should be `find(hello, words.end(), "James")`, since otherwise James might be found before Hello.

Answer (score 1):

To count:

```
std::ifstream infile("hamlet.txt");
std::size_t count = 0;
for (std::string word; infile >> word; ++count) { }
```

To count only between start and stop:

```
std::ifstream infile("hamlet.txt");
std::size_t count = 0;
bool active = false;

for (std::string word; infile >> word; )
{
     if (!active && word == "Hello") { active = true; }
     if (!active) continue;
     if (word == "James") break;
     ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "return nextword;" should instead be "else return nextword;" or else you are returning from the function getNextWord every time, no matter what the char is.

```
string ReadWords::getNextWord()
{
    bool pWord = false;
    char c;
    while((c = wordfile.get()) !=EOF)
    {
        if (!(isspace(c)))
        {
            nextword.append(1, c);
        }

        else return nextword;//only returns on a space
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To count all words:

```
std::ifstream f("hamlet.txt");
std::cout << std::distance (std::istream_iterator<std::string>(f),
                            std::istream_iterator<std::string>()) << '\n';
```

To count between two words:

```
std::ifstream f("hamlet.txt");
std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(f), end;
int count = 0;
while (std::find(it, end, "Hello") != end)
  while (++it != end && *it != "James")
    ++count;
std::cout << count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
below the line

```
nextword.append(1, c);
```

add

```
continue;
```